# Download "invalid characters"

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded Nvidia JetPack 3.1 from Nvidia Developer website. Download completes but on opening I get: "There was a problem opening the file "/etc/etc...linux-x64.run" The file you opened has some invalid characters" followed by a warning that you can corrupt the file if you continue. Then there is a selection window for Character Encoding indicating "Current Locale (UTF-8). This has happened several times using two different browsers. I remember a similar problem downloading graphic drivers.

Comment: Hi! How are you opening the file, exactly? Please [edit] your question to add some more clarification. :)

Comment: A bit hard to understand the question, but aren't you trying to open a binary file as text? Sounds like it..

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to execute that file, not open it in a text editor. Apparently it's a binary file, no human readable script.

So to do that, first make it executable from a terminal using

```
chmod +x /PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE.run
```

Then you can simply execute it by typing its filename (including absolute or relative path).

Comment: Think you could write just for clarification that he should add `./` before the file name if he opens it in the same folder. If the OP was trying to open the file as text he might have trouble with that too.